# Problems graphing two differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have two differential equations and I am trying to graph the $V(t)$ but I am not able to produce a graph.

Equations: $$ \frac{dV(t)}{dt} = \pi\, P(t)-\sigma\, V(t)\qquad\mbox{ and}\qquad \frac{dP(t)}{dt}= \beta\, V(t) T- \delta\, P(t)$$

```
Clear[system, nV, nP]
system[π_, σ_, α_, ρ_, β_, δ_, d_,
   nV0_, nP0_, tmin_, tmax_] := 
    system[π, σ, α, ρ, β, δ, d, nV0,
    nP0, tmin, tmax]  = 
  NDSolve[{nV'[t] == π*nP[t] - σ *nV[t], 
    nP'[t] == β*nV[t]*d - δ*nP[t], nV[0]  == nV0, 
    nP[0] == nP0}, {nV[t], nP[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

Now when I want to graph I used:

```
Plot[Evaluate[ nV[t] /. system[1.5, 6, 1, 3.5 10^-3, 5.7 10^-7, 0.47, 7.3 10^6, 0, 
0, 0, 100] ], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}]
```

It says error when I do this. Anyone have any ideas why this is occurring.

Comment: Just remove `Pi` from the "system"  or replace it with another name.

Comment: The symbol $\pi$ is reserved, so you should not try to use it as a variable.  Also,   the point $(nV, nP) = (0,0)$ is an equilibrium point.  So, with `{0,0}` as your initial condition, the solution is zero for any choice of coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your issues by following the comments.

Here is an improved version of your code. The main idea is to use `ParametricNDSolveValue` instead of `SetDelay`.

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{nV'[t] == p0*nP[t] - σ*nV[t], 
                              nP'[t] == β*nV[t]*d - δ*nP[t], nV[0] == nV0, 
                             nP[0] == nP0}, {nV[t], nP[t]}, {t, tmin,  tmax}, 
                              {p0, σ, α, ρ, β, δ, d, nV0, nP0, tmin, tmax}];

Plot[{sol[1.5, 6, 1, 3.5 10^-3, 5.7 10^-7, 0.47, 7.3 10^6, 0.3, 1, 0, 
    100][[1]], sol[1.5, 6, 1, 3.5 10^-3, 5.7 10^-7, 0.47, 7.3 10^6, 0.3, 1, 0, 
    100][[2]]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```